# Can't get the right camera settings that match the scene

Tags: camera

I need the plane object to match the black surface of the ipod with no modification to the transformation/ translation or scale of either the plane or the character. The distane between them in 3d scence quite matches the reallife image.

[image]

I have tried much, even tried BLAM add-on. But nothing came right...
   Would be nice if anyone can figure the right camera settings for me!!

Blend file: [image]

Comment: Do you use camera tracking? I think if I open the blend file, the image won't show

Comment: Nope. I just want to blend the objects to the real-life scene without changing the loc/rot/scale of the 3d objects. And I've packed the image to the blend file!

Comment: @thododo Keep in mind that the blend file does not save the images used unless you **pack** them into the file. Please pack your 11.jpg image or make it somehow available. Otherwise its going to be hard to help you.